# "conpositio" or "compositio"?

Tags: vocabulary

In the entry of the Gaffiot dictionary for "compositio", there is a reference to Cicero De legimus (Liber II [55]).

However in this passage, according to Wikisource, Cicero wrote "conpositio" (that is with a n and not an m before the p).

What is the correct form?

Answer (score 6):

Both forms were used during the classical age, and both were common enough and correct. This applies to all(?) words with *-np-*, in which the *n* could be assimilated to the *p*, to form *-mp-*, but it was by no means always assimilated. Perhaps it depended on the author and the period?